# Preventing buffer overflow in C

Tags: c, overflow

Is there any way to prevent buffer overflow in C ?
If I can't determine the string length how can I know when to stop ?

```
x = malloc(strlen(unsafe_string) + 1);
memcpy(x, unsafe_string, strlen(unsafe_string) + 1);
```

Comment: What do you mean "if I can't determine the string length"? You just did, with `strlen`.

Comment: But the unsafe_string can be not null terminated

Comment: You can use `strnlen` (if you're really worried about non-null terminated strings) to get the string length. Also, you should check if your `malloc` succeeded.

Comment: @Zack Then you don't use `strlen()` but expect an explicit length to be available along with it.

Comment: @Zack: If the string is not null terminated, someone else will have told you the length of the data.

Comment: This code in this post is an example of the Narrator's Dilemma: On the one hand, you shouldn't be stating something obvious ("this is a cactus", when the picture shows a cactus), but on the other hand, you also shouldn't say something unrelated ("the desert is dry"). It's a lose-lose situation.

Comment: Accept the limitations of your language, (for they are legion), and don't do silly things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strnlen` and check for `malloc` success, like so

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *unsafe_string = "hello, world"; /* whatever */

  size_t max_len = 1024 * 1024; /* one megabyte */
  size_t len = strnlen(unsafe_string, max_len) + 1; /* the smaller of the length, 
                                                       or 1 mb */
  char *x = malloc(len * sizeof(char *)); /* malloc len */
  if (x != NULL) { /* check for success */
    strncpy(x, unsafe_string, len); /* safe string copy */
    x[len+1] = '\0';
    puts(x);
    free(x);
  }
}
```

Which just prints

```
$ gcc hello.c
$ ./a.out 
hello, world
```

here.

Comment: What does using `strnlen()` improve? (especially when passing it an arbitrary constant pulled out of a hat)

Comment: Can you make `unsafe_string` a little less chipper than `"hello, world"`? ;-)

Comment: `len * sizeof(char *)` is funny if one is into this kind of humor.